# Default initialisation creating an Array of struct vs class objects

Tags: c#, .net, types

I understand that struct is value type and class is reference type in .Net. I would like to know if there is any better solution here.

Example,

```
public struct Holder
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public Holder()
    {
        this.Value = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Usage of this struct:

```
void SomeFunction(int n)
{
    Holder[] valueHolders = new Holder[n];
    ...
    valueHolders[0].Value = someValue;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Now just changing `Holder` to `class`. It throws an `null` object reference because `valueHolders` contails all values as `null`.

Now I have changed my code to

```
valueHolders[0] = new Holder();
valueHolders[0].Value = someValue;
```

It works fine. Is there any way to create all elements in `valueHolders` at once like it was doing when it was a `struct` type.

Comment: Are you sure `public Holder()` even compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# requires a reference type to be initialized explicitly. This can be done quite easily within a loop:

```
Holder[] valueHolders = new Holder[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    valueHolders[i] = new Holder();
}
```

You can take this a bit further and expose a static method on your class like this:

```
public class Holder    {
    static public Holder[] InitArray(ulong length) {
        Holder[] holders = new Holder[length];
        for (ulong i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            holders[i] = new Holder;
        }
        return holders;
    }
}

...

var valueHolders = Holder.InitArray(n);
```

You can take it even further with a generic extension method:

```
public static class ArrayInitializer
{
    public static T[] Init<T>(this T[] array) where T : new()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new T();
        }
        return array;
    }
}

...

var valueHolders = new Holder[n].Init();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was expecting something different than this.

Comment: What were you expecting? The answer to your question is: "No, there is no way to do it like it's done with structs, since objects work differently. And here's a way how it can be done anyway."

Comment: @Dennis, the correct term is “reference type”, not “object”. That's because `struct`s are `object`s too (i.e. they inherit from `object`).

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying, @svick. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: And you generic version wouldn't compile as it is. You are missing the constraint `where T : new()`.

Comment: That's what happens if you quickly hack an answer together. But OP seems not to be interested in this anyway.